# javascript file doesn't find in my express app

Tags: javascript, express

I got this error
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express()
const { join } = require('path')

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname,'/public')))
```

my folder structure:

[image]

the js is for survey.html:

```
<script src="/assets/index.js"></script>
```

anyone know why I got this error?

i tried

```
<script src="./assets/index.js"></script>
```

doesn't work

Comment: app.use(express.static(join(__dirname,'public'))) Use this

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo: You said `'/public'` but the public folder is not in the root of the **filesystem**. (That argument is a *directory* name not a relative URL).

Answer (score 2):

It should be `app.use(express.static(join(__dirname,'public')))`. adding `/` to the `public` means it looks in the root filesystem.

EDIT:

Oh, it is actually in the comment:

> app.use(express.static(join(__dirname,'public'))) Use this  – **Yatin Gaikwad**